# How do you call a Component that is within a sub folder in angular/ionic?

Tags: angular, ionic4

I have a component that I created that's in this path /app/components/my-component

With the component that are in app/ path I could easily go:

```
<app-my-component></app-my-component>
```

and it works fine. but as soon as I move the component to the sub folder I struggle to call the component:

I tried doing this:

```
<app-components-my-component></app-components-my-component>
```

And it didn't work.

I really apologize if I am using wrong terminology, e.g calling instead of injection.

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't matter where the componente is from the path. All references to the component in the path have to be updated. Also in the module of the component. with an editor like webstorm this is done very elegantly via the refactor function. You don't need to use path in the components selector name.
Please check all references.